# Designing a chat application

Tags: android

I am trying to design a simple chat application for android. The concept is, users have to register and login to their account and can chat with each other. A basic chat...

Can anyone please tell me the simplest and the most efficient way to design a chat application... Any input will be valuable. Any samples also will be of great help...

EDIT:

I am trying to use jwchat.org as a sample jabber server to establish connection. Can anyone plz help me with a tutorial or sample code of how to do it...

Comment: There are numerous existing chat protocols in existence; some are their own special protocol, others simply coordinate through HTTP. The most simple protocol I know about (assuming raw socket access) is IRC -- Internet Relay Chat. In any case, I would define my requirements and resources better, and then choose an *exiting* protocol that fits well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first have a server in order for the users to create and login to their accounts. Then based on the server / chat protocols, you implement the chat program.

You might also need to write the server program in order to communicate to the clients based on the protocol.

Unless you're talking about serverless communications, where applications communicate between each other via means of bluetooth or wireless, you just need to do Discovery, Establishment, and Communication.

Answer (score 0):

There is a service from Google, called Google Cloud Messaging, which provides somewhat similar experience in writing a chat app.

I would suggest to first start communicating two apps through a server where a Java servlet will handle all the incoming messages and forward them to the other app connected. If the receieving end is offline, then store the messages and when it gets online, pop all the stored messages and send them.

When this is done, create a table of users and add the functionality of registration and the chat will then be among 2 users among them, connected.